# can I set default parameter value in construture?

Tags: java

Can I set the default arument value in Construct function something like
?

```
public class XLSReader {
  public XLSReader(String filename="XYZ.xls") {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Java doesn't support optional parameters. You can use overloading and chaining though:

```
public XlsReader() {
    this("XYZ.xls");
}

public XlsReader(String filename) {
    // Use filename here
}
```

(This applies to methods as well as constructors.)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Default parameter is not supported in Java.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot but what you can do is to have 2 constructors like this:

```
public class XLSReader {
  String filename;

  // constructor with a filename argument
  public XLSReader(String filename) {
     this.filename = filename;
  }

  // default constructor will fill-in "default value" XYZ.xls
  public XLSReader() {
     this.filename = "XYZ.xls";
  }
}
```